# How to show the simple equivalence?

Tags: integration, partial-derivative, equivalence-relations

I come across the following equivalence of integrations:

$$\int\left[-I \left(h\right){\partial h \over \partial \tau}+{\partial h \over \partial x}{\partial \over \partial \tau} \left({\partial h \over \partial x}\right)\right]\mathrm dx=-\int h^3 \left[{\partial \over \partial x} 
\left(I(h)+ {\partial^2 h \over \partial x^2} \right)
 \right]^2\mathrm dx$$

where $h(x,\tau)$ subjects to periodic boundary conditions

$$h[0,\tau]=h[l,\tau]$$
$$h_x[0,\tau]=h_x[l,\tau]$$
$$h_{xx}[0,\tau]=h_{xx}[l,\tau]$$
$$h_{xxx}[0,\tau]=h_{xxx}[l,\tau]$$

But I can't derive it from left-hand side to the right-hand side. I have tried integrate by parts with these periodic B.C.s. Can anyone give me some advice?

Comment: what is I(h) ??

Comment: @Arashium,I(h) just is a unknown function of h.

Comment: [Related question on Physics.](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/164215/how-can-i-show-the-time-derivative-of-an-energy-functional)

Answer (score 0):

What you say does not seem to be correct. Think about function h that only depends on $\tau$:

$$h=h(\tau)$$

Then both sides would be different. This equation is wrong for general case of h.

Comment: @ Arashium,thanks! Yes you are right, I think I should post the original problem. I may do some mistake.The full issue is: How can one transform $h_\tau=-\left[h^3 \left[ I(h)+ {s \over 3} h_{xx} \right]_x  \right]_x$ to this form ${d \over d \tau} \int \left[ -\int I(h) dh + {s \over 6} \left(h_x \right)^2 \right] dx= -\int h^3 \left[\left( I(h)+ {s \over 3} h_{xx} \right)_x \right]^2 dx $ ?

Comment: @lxy what do you mean by $\frac s3$?

Comment: Hi @ Arashium! It is just a constant :). I just maintain the full problem. I have a hint: we can multiply the original equation by $ I(h)+ {s \over 3} h_{xx}$ and integrate it by parts with periodic boundary conditions. But I still can not get the desired final form.

Comment: Better to fix the question too. I think there is a problem in your question. the solution is that if you substitute the right side of #1 into right side of #2 and also bring the $\frac{d}{d\tau}$ into the integral of left side of #2, you can simplify it and you must result into something evident. If not, look for mistakes in the question

Comment: @ Arashium. You may mean substituting the right side of #1 into **left side** of #2 and also bring the ${d\over d \tau}$ into the integral of left side of #2 then simplifying it ?

Comment: @ Arashium.I tried as follows. LHS of #2 $=\int \left[-{\partial \over \partial \tau}\int I(h)dh+ {s \over 3} h_x h_{x \tau}\right] dx=\int\left[-{\partial \over \partial h}\left(\int I(h)dh\right){\partial h\over \partial\tau}+{s\over 3}h_x{\partial\over\partial x}h_{\tau}\right]dx= \int\left[-I(h)h_\tau+{s\over3}h_x{\partial\over\partial x}(h_\tau)\right] dx $.

Comment: Then taking place $h_\tau$ in the above result by RHS of #1 but still can't reach RHS of #2. The final form is similar, but not exactly. Could you find where I made a mistake? Actually, this is an equation from a paper, which should be correct.